# Loop over td's from all tables inside div container? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over 3 different tables and get `td` id's. All three tables are in the same `div` container. I do have the same class on all three tables. Here is example:

```
<div id="myContainer">
  <table class="myTbl">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Text 1</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td id="el_1"></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="myTbl">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Text 2</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td id="el_2"></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="myTbl">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Text 3</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td id="el_3"></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery. The code below only looped over first table

```
$('table.myTbl tbody tr td').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('id'))
});
```

then I tried this. This is the same as above. only the id from the first table showed in the console

```
$('#myContainer table tbody tr td').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('id'))
});
```

I'm wondering how to loop over `td` id's from all tables inside of the `div` container?

Comment: both of your selectors are working for me - I get `el_1, el_2, el_3` logged in console. Are you expecting different output?

Comment: @Rhumborl I think I have the problem in my JSON file then. Each table id should have matching key in the JSON file.